# E488 trailing characters VIM

Tags: vim

I am very new to VIM and am trying to figure out where the trailing characters are. I have looked through :help and the meaning of the error message. As far as I can tell, am I supposed to replace "'s with the escape character? What would the syntax look like? Thank you.

[image: VIM]

[Using :set list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN9y8.jpg)

Comment: Please update your question to include what you entered to receive this message...

Comment: I am following a walk-through and this was the script provided.

Comment: I think I answered your question. If not, It happens when I type :q /opt/tmp/file.py

Answer (score 1):

The `:quit` command never takes an argument.

```
:q /opt/tmp/file.py
```

should either be:

```
:wq /opt/tmp/file.py    " write buffer to file /opt/tmp/file.py then quit window
```

or:

```
:q!                     " quit window without writing to file
```